# php-fpm user unable to run node commands

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, vagrant, centos7

- I have a vagrant instance running CentOS7.
- This vagrant instance is running Nginx to host websites locally on my mac.
- I have php-fpm running to support processing of php files.
- Finally, I have a php
  file that calls a node.js script.

What I am finding is that the user:group that php-fpm is configured under is unable to run node commands. I have node installed (via nvm) on the user I ssh into the box with, but the php-fpm user has no access to that installation.

Is there a way to install Node/Npm in a way that the php-fpm user-group can access?

Thank you

Comment: This is a better question for [sf].

Comment: Could you give us result of `sudo getenforce`?

Comment: And if anyone tells you to turn off SELinux, ignore them.

Comment: Are you sure `node` is in your `$PATH` even? And , well, errors would help a lot, what _actual error_ are you getting trying to run node?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `node` is not in the `$PATH` for the php-fpm user. The error is literally that it can't find `node` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of miken32, I posted this in server fault.

https://serverfault.com/questions/833825/php-fpm-user-unable-to-run-node-commands/834000#834000

The suggestion posted there ended up helping me out, though I'm not totally sure why :).